Slack file download using url_private
I am experiencing difficulties downloading files from channels where the bot is not present. Specifically, I am utilizing url_private along with the required authentication token and files:read scope. Although I am able to retrieve file information successfully, I encounter an issue where the file does not download when using the fetch function in Node.js. Interestingly, when I paste the same URL directly into a browser, the file downloads without any problems.
The file downloads successfully using url_private when the bot is present in the channel, whether I use the fetch function or paste the link directly into a browser. However, when attempting to download files from channels where the bot is not added, the file downloads via the browser but not using the fetch function in Node.js.

You need to pass the Slack bot oauth token as Authorization header in the GET request. This is the reason the files are getting downloaded via browser (because the session is already established on the browser); if you try to use the same url_private in an incognito window, I am guessing that will not lead to the file getting downloaded.
Here is the cURL for your reference; it shows how the slack bot oauth token is used:
curl --location 'https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T000000008-F07AP4PHTNG/download/img.jpg' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer xoxb-5719057000000-6194513000000-pnDCXO3Q78Dn1p5LkN000000'

